# issues adding components to vb6 after registering them

Tags: vb6, components

I'm having issues with a few `.ocx` files in `vb6`. I have 2 components registered but when I attempted to add both into my project it says that I need to register them.  I have tried copying new files into the `sysWOW64` folders and still it does not work.

Comment: Have you already run `regsvr32` on them then?

Comment: Is it complaining about component registration or about design-time licensing?

Comment: I did run regsvr32. its complaining saying that the objects aren't registered when I did register them.

Answer (score 0):

This occasionally happens when there is some corruption and conflict in the registry. One way to fix this is to place the two items in a folder within the project and add them by manually going to the reference and selecting that local copy, it will automatically register it as a new object and often (although not always) will fix the corruption by tagging the new path and it often resolves the issue you are facing. The only problem is that in the future projects, you may need to repeat the process or have access to the items.

The cleaner approach is to find all instances of the files on the system by doing an advanced search and finding ALL COPIES of them on the system, often they are all over the place. Once you have those paths, you need to `regsvr32 /u <filepath.filename>` each one to clean remove them from the registry and then place them in a common area and then register them from ONE location using `regsvr32 <filepath.filename>` and now things should work fairly cleanly.

Easiest way to find all instances on your machine (at least for me) is to simple go to your command prompt (if using more recent than XP, then as administrator) and then simply type:

```
C:
cd\
dir /s <filename.ext> > c:\files.txt
```

and wait until its done, at that point you open that file and it should give you all the paths to the files you need and you can easily turn the text file into a batch file by adding the commands you need to unreg and run it, voila, quick and fairly painless. If at anytime you unreg and it whines about it not being registered or can't do it, don't worry, just acknowledge and move on. Some OCX and DLL don't have registration entry points. If you register and it complains saying it can't do it, then you pretty much have no choice but to it the way I mentioned at the very beginning, by direct linking in your reference and having it drop into your project.

Final note, unless they are 64 bit compatible, you don't need and often shouldn't put them in the WOW system folder but rather system and system32 folders depending on version control and binary control of the original OCX.